# Get all fields inside expression

Tags: jasper-reports, expression

I not using *Java* code to generate this report, just the *iReport*. And I want to find a simple way to get all fields in some kind of index arrays.

Sample: I have a query that returns 10 fields, the number of rows are irrelevant.
So i want do create a expression, could be inside a parameter, text field, static field, doesn't matter, but i want to take all fields at once... :

```
$Fields.get(0) + $Fields.get(1) + $Fields.get(2)...
```

Anybody knows something about that? It's possible to do this?

Comment: are you getting fields from query

Comment: Is your report based on a SQL query, from which you are getting your parameters?

Comment: Yes, fields from very simples query, database: Oracle.

Comment: Then, why don't you take all the fields by using their name in the query inside the expression? Meaning, you should be something like: "$F{FIRST_FIELD}". So, the Text Field (using a static field in this case would not work) must have this expression:"" + $F{FIRST_FIELD}+" "+$F{SECOND_FIELD}+ " "+... and so on

Comment: I'm trying to do a kind os dynamic report without using crosstabs... the reason of this is the extreme delay in generation of a large, very large massive data of database... So, my attempt is to control this fields list/array that returns from database and try to ready then using their positions, like i say: $Fields.get(0), $Fields.get(1) and so on... If i can do this, i remove the process of system to build a runtime pivot table, getting speedy response report execution...